# Is this statement grammatically correct? - Did you add another piece of code

Tags: meaning-in-context, tense

I want to say that to someone that have they added a new piece of code in their existing code. So is the below code fine or it can be said differently.

> Did you add another piece of code.

I am kind of confused, What if I use "added" for making it past tense "Have you added another piece of code" something like that? , or should I use past perfect for this scenario?

Is it also a simple past tense?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, kup. Do you have any specific concerns about this sentence? Why do you think it might not be OK?

Comment: @JavaLatte I am kinda confused, What if i use `added` for making it past tense "Have you added another peice of code" something like that? , or should  i use past perfect for this scenario

Comment: Did is already past.

Comment: @kup Thanks I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a correct past tense question

| Statement | Question | Tense |
| --- | --- | --- |
| You added ... | Did you add ... | past, with do support for question. |
| You have added ... | Have you added ... | present perfect. No "do support" |

Both past tense and present perfect could be used here, in speech or writng, and have similar meaning.

Comment: Thanks can you  please also tell, Which one is more appropriate for writing and which one for when speaking?

Comment: Wow, that table is neat!

Comment: @James K how did you do the table?

Comment: @Brad look here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

Questions need to end with a question mark.

> Did you add another piece of code?